# How to get the difference between two timestamps in days?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to get the difference between two timestamps in days?

```
  "min": 1487344607000,
  "max": 1492442207000,
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python - Difference between two unix timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45603232/python-difference-between-two-unix-timestamps)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a quick example,

```
import datetime

min = min/1000           #removing milli seconds
max = max/1000

min = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(min)
max = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(max)

print("Total Days : " + str((max-min).days))
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 interpretations:

```
import datetime
date1=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(min/1000)
date2=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(max/1000)
delta = date2-date1
days = delta.days
```

Or if the difference must be a full day:

```
days=(max-min)/86400
```