# How to find the difference between two times in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find the difference between two times in Python. It is guaranteed that the times are on the same day.

```
#For example
s1 = '13:00' 
s2 = '12:58'
```

The difference between these two times should be 2 mins. The output should be: `2`

This is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
s1 = '13:00'
s2 = '12:58'
FMT = '%H:%M'
tdelta = datetime.strptime(s2, FMT) - datetime.strptime(s1, FMT)
print(tdelta)
```

But it returns:

```
-1 day, 23:58:00
```

How can i fix this and return my time as: `2`

Comment: Switch the order of `s1` and `s2`: `tdelta = datetime.strptime(s1, FMT) - datetime.strptime(s2, FMT)`

Comment: Maybe subtract the smaller one from the larger one instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python - Difference between two unix timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45603232/python-difference-between-two-unix-timestamps)

Comment: Convert to minutes since `00:00`, then subtract

Comment: @sacul Thanks! It solved it. I really didn't see that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `abs` for the result i.e. `abs(datetime.strptime(s2, FMT) - datetime.strptime(s1, FMT))`:

```
from datetime import datetime
s1 = '13:00'
s2 = '12:58'
FMT = '%H:%M'
tdelta = abs(datetime.strptime(s2, FMT) - datetime.strptime(s1, FMT))
print(tdelta)
```

Result:

```
0:02:00
```

---

## Update:

As suggested in comment below, if you specifically want difference in `minutes`, you can use `.total_seconds()/60` in `tdelta`:

```
from datetime import datetime
s1 = '13:00'
s2 = '12:58'
FMT = '%H:%M'
tdelta = datetime.strptime(s2, FMT) - datetime.strptime(s1, FMT)
minutes_difference = abs(tdelta.total_seconds()/60)
print(minutes_difference)
```

Result:

```
2.0
```

Comment: Difference in minutes:  [timedelta.total_seconds()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) / 60

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Python pandas library:

```
import pandas as pd

time_1 = pd.Timestamp('13:00')
time_2 = pd.Timestamp('12:58')
delta = time_1 - time_2
print(delta)
```

The Timestamp() method will allow you to create a simple Timestamp. Here is your output:

```
0 days 00:02:00
```

It takes as a given that the Timestamps are on the same day unless you specify otherwise.