# Python calculating Unix timestamp difference in Minutes from a given epoch value

Tags: python, datetime

I would like to know the best approach from the below solutions to calculate the time difference **in minutes** between the current Linux timestamp with the given *epoch* value (for example "*1512082800*" extracted from ETL data):

[python - Difference between two unix timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45603232/python-difference-between-two-unix-timestamps)

```
old = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(epoch_value)) # eg: 1512082800
cur = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
print((cur - old).total_seconds() / 60) # difference between two Unix timestamps in minutes
```

[Date difference in minutes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788871/date-difference-in-minutes-in-python/39181657)

```
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
cur = datetime.datetime.strptime(time.strftime(fmt), fmt)
epoch = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(1512082800)).strftime(fmt)
old = datetime.datetime.strptime(epoch, fmt)

old = time.mktime(old.timetuple())
cur = time.mktime(cur.timetuple())

# They are now in seconds, subtract and then divide by 60 to get minutes
print int(cur-old) / 60
```

Comment: Can't you use `time.time()`? Like `dt_min = (time.time() - epoch_value)/60`?

Comment: @MrFuppes, yep that gives the result as well, kudos

Comment: using `time.time()` also seems to be slightly better in terms of performance, see the little timeit comparison below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is probably best to use `time.time()` here [[docs]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time) - since this gives you seconds since the epoch, you can directly calculate the desired delta in minutes as `(time.time() - timestamp)/60`.

Timeit comparison vs. getting the current timestamp as`datetime.datetime.utcnow()`:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

%timeit (time.time() - 1512082800) / 60
221 ns ± 10.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit (datetime.utcnow().timestamp() - 1512082800) / 60
848 ns ± 14.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```