# Python3 check if int epochtime are less then X hours diff

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, epoch, timedelta

I have two ints that represents epochtimes:

```
x1 = 1597611600
x2 = 1597489203
```

I want to check if there is less then 72 hours between them.
What is the best way to do so in Python3?
Please notice that both are int.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You could do it by the tools stated in your tags.

Comment: @adamkwm It didn't work because x1, x2 are strings and I couldnt find how to use timedelta

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python - Difference between two unix timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45603232/python-difference-between-two-unix-timestamps)

Comment: Do you know what an Epoch time represents, and in which unit? Can you calculate the difference? Can you calculate what 72 hours represent in this unit? Can you do a comparison? What part of this is your actual problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert epoch timestamps to datetime objects, perform subtraction and compare the result to timedelta object. However, you can simply do a comparision in seconds.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt, timedelta as td
def epoch_diff_within(ts1, ts2, hr):
    d1 = dt.fromtimestamp(x1)
    d2 = dt.fromtimestamp(x2)
    return d1 - d2 < td(hours=hr)

def epoch_diff_within2(ts1, ts2, hr):
    return ts1 - ts2 < hr * 60 * 60

x1 = 1597611600
x2 = 1597489203
print(epoch_diff_within(x1, x2, 72)) # Output: True
print(epoch_diff_within2(x1, x2, 72)) # Output: True
print(epoch_diff_within(x1, x2, 24)) # Output: False
print(epoch_diff_within2(x1, x2, 24)) # Output: False
```